# Emails sent from php codeigniter unable to receive on specific domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, phpmailer

In authentication i have reset password from where i have a following code to send email using php codeigniter.

```
/*********** other code *************/
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('xyz@myexpdomain.com', 'HRMS');
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject('Reset Password');
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
/*********** other code *************/
```

in `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv CI_ENV production
</IfModule>
```

Hence in `application/config/production/email.php`

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'xyz@myexpdomain.com',
'smtp_pass' => '********',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
```

Working fine but.
We have another domain and created Gsuite associated email for that another domain says `"myexp2domain.com"`. when we use these email id (`$to`) the emails are not received in inbox/spam.

We are able to receive emails if email id is from Gmail, youmail, etc.

I am not able to imagine what might be possible reasons, can you please suggest me.